# Cost of having a channel with very large limit

Tags: go

Basically what the title says. I am wondering what the cons are for having a large limit for a channel size

`k := make(chan int, 100000000)`

Comment: it will comsume a lot of memory if it gets full

Comment: And what if it's not full. Why should one choose to have a smaller channel size?

Comment: It will consume the same amount of memory whether it's full or not.  You're probably making a design mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will allocate a lot of memory.  In the `makechan` implementation, we can see that it fully allocates the send buffer when you create the channel:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/chan.go#L71

So for your specific example, you would be allocating at least 400MB (on 32-bit systems) or 800MB (on 64-bit systems) of memory up front.

If you find yourself needing ultra-large buffers in your channels, is it possible that some other data structure might fit your needs better?

Comment: Probably. I am using a channel to build an asynchronous job queue. Basically, there is an enqueue method that sends struct to the channel and periodically there is a goroutine that will receive all the struct and `process` them. There is also another goroutine that would insert a nil to the channel to stop the other goroutine from processing and rest.

Comment: Of course, for my specific example, I don't need 100000000 limit :) It's much much less.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to have a big queue, but not all the time, how about making your own growing/shrinking one?

```
func makeQueue() (enqueue chan<- int, dequeue <-chan int) {
    enq, deq := make(chan int), make(chan int)
    var queue []int
    go func() {
        for {
            if len(queue) == 0 {
                queue = append(queue, <-enq)
            }

            select {
            case v := <-enq:
                queue = append(queue, v)
            case deq <- queue[0]:
                queue = append([]int{}, queue[1:]...)
            }
        }
    }()
    return enq, deq
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/q_Uw-E9NQb

Caveat: as implemented, the dequeue operation copies the whole underlying slice. Although copying is idiomatic in Go, profiling may showcase that a linked list (like http://godoc.org/container/list) might be faster. You can also arrange to extract from the queue in bigger chunks, and have dequeue read from those chunks, reducing copying operations.

Comment: Or you could compare `len(queue)` and `cap(queue)` when deciding whether to shrink it or not.

Comment: It is a terrible idea in my opinion, you loose all the chain of blockage between producers and consumers. To me this is an oom time bomb.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to gather some ideas from the channels package as well: https://github.com/eapache/channels

It supports channels that grow without using excess space when full. It also has a batching function that sounds like it might be useful for your purposes.